# Customised output name in global environment using R functions

Tags: r, dataframe, function, customization

I am new to R programming and a bit stumped on this question. I have 3 different databases and I want to extract 2 sets of test and train data from them. I know how to do this with individual line of codes but that is repetitive task hence I want to automate this using function.

I want my output name to carry Data base name, followed by test or train, followed by number and I want to export them directly into Global environment. Here is the code that I wrote (Using MTCARS) as sample data base which does not work. I have also given my desired output

Just to be clear this is just an example. There are different areas where I want to customise output from function(x) in global environment without needing to write the code over and over again.

```
mydata<-mtcars
 
output_2_set_test_train <-function(x){

  library(caTools)
  i=1
  dfname <- deparse(substitute(x))

  while(i<=2){
    sample.split(x[[1]], SplitRatio = .75)->split_tag
    subset(x, split_tag==T)->> paste0(dfname,"_","train","_",i)
    subset(x, split_tag==F)->> paste0(dfname,"_","test","_",i)
    i=i+1
  }
}
 
output_2_set_test_train(mydata)
```

After running my function, I want my global environment to have the following data frames with this specific name -

#1 data frame named -> mydata_train_1
#2 data frame named -> mydata_test_1
#3 data frame named -> mydata_train_2
#4 data frame named -> mydata_test_2

I tried to do a lot of search on this but couldn't get any answers that work.

Can someone please help me to correct the code?

Comment: This is fundamentally a **very bad idea**, even if it worked. Don’t assign stuff from inside a function into the global environment. Instead, *return the values*. Some other notes: calling `library` inside a function is also a bad idea because it causes another global side effect. Writing `foo==TRUE` is redundant; just write `foo`. Same for `foo==FALSE`: just write `! foo`. And don’t use the shortcuts `T` and `F`, since these are *variables* that can be overwritten. Lastly, your `while` loop is unnecessarily convoluted — this should be a `for` loop or, better yet, an `lapply` call.

Comment: One more: left-to-right assignment is unidiomatic and should be replaced by right-to-left assignment to make the assignee more visible. I suggest you forget that the `->`/`->>` operator even exists, and never use it. Its existence in R really is a mistake (there’s a reason virtually no other language has an equivalent).

Comment: Hello @KonradRudolph, thank you for your feedback. As I mentioned I am completely new to R and to programming. Appreciate your feedback. It will help me learn and improve but I have been trying to teach myself and have no idea about idomatic / unidiomatic code. I will read up. The reason I used -> / ->> is because I took basic course from MIT on EDX and they suggested in R use -> instead of =.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see Konrad's warnings about this type of coding and also about the conventions in R. Almost nothing in your code is idiomatic.

You would need to replace these lines:

```
subset(x, split_tag==T)->> paste0(dfname,"_","train","_",i)
subset(x, split_tag==F)->> paste0(dfname,"_","test","_",i)
```

with something like:

```
assign(paste0(dfname,"_","train","_",i), subset(x, split_tag==T), envir = globalenv())
assign(paste0(dfname,"_","test","_",i), subset(x, split_tag==F), envir = globalenv())
```

Comment: If you help people writing bad code, *at least* please mention that writing this is actually a bad idea.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, the stylistic issues are obvious to me, and I have not come across `assign` much in examples, so I wouldn't normally use it...But not being a programmer, I don't think I know why this is "fundamentally" a bad idea. It kind of sounds like the "you shouldn't use a for loop in R". If your goal is, say, to actually see your objects in the Global Environment where your IDE may provide you immediate information for your analysis; what's the big deal?

Comment: It’s not a “stylistic issue”, it’s a *code quality issue*. And it’s in a fundamentally different class of “bad idea” than “you shouldn’t use loops”, although the latter is *also* not merely a stylistic issue. — And, yes, there *are* valid uses, but >99% of all Stack Overflow requests don’t fall into this category, and I see no indication that this question is in the 1%. The purpose of answers on this site is to *help*. This very much includes giving feedback on questionable/bad code.

Comment: Sorry, I am not trying to have an argument. I was asking because I genuinely want to know what is normally wrong with assigning inside a function in general

Comment: I specifically used `assign` and not simply `<<-` because intuitively it seems relatively safe to assign somewhere on purpose as opposed to just letting it match whatever object it encounters... but I'm not sure if I'm missing something else?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I do understand and agree that my coding might be bad cause I am a newbie but not sure why the idea is bad and how would you suggest to implement this idea? As you mentioned that there are valid uses and all I am trying to do is to reduce the number of lines in a code that I have to write over and over again. Do you have any suggestion on what is a good idea to avoid repetitive coding?

Answer (score 0):

One strong concept of R is that functions should have as few side-effects as possible. A *side-effect* is any action apart from returning a value.

There are several obvious exceptions to this (a function that writes data to a file, for example, obviously *needs* to have a side-effect) but creating variables in the calling/global scope is almost never a good idea, because *return values* are the intended mechanism for this.

In your case, you’d generally return a list of the two values. Along with some other changes to the code, the result would look as follows:

```
output_2_set_test_train <- function (x) {
  is_training <- caTools::sample.split(x[[1L]], SplitRatio = 0.75)
  list(
    train = subset(x, is_training),
    test = subset(x, ! is_training)
  )
}
```

And you’d use the function like this:

```
data <- output_2_set_test_train(mtcars)
```

Now `data$train` contains the training set, and `data$test` contains the test set.

A few notes on the implementation:

1. Obviously the most important change is that we are returning the value of the function rather than assigning it into the global environment.
2. I don’t use `library`, because that’s another *global* side-effect: `library` attaches packages globally, not locally (if you’re interested in a better approach, check out the package ‘[box](https://klmr.me/box/#loading-code)’).

   - Instead, we use `caTools::sample.split` to refer to this particular function from the ‘caTools’ package inside the function
3. I’ve removed the useless `==T` and `==F` comparisons.
4. I’ve completely removed the `while` loop and everything connected to it.
5. I’ve renamed `split_tag` to `is_training`, which is a more descriptive name.

Comment: thanks for this. One last question on your code. It is a lot cleaner but the reason why I had a loop in it was to have 2 distinct set of train and test data and also to avoid writing further code as every time I will have to type the manual code i.e. mydata_test_1 = as.data.frame(data$test) and then mydata_test_2 = as.data.frame(data$test2) etc. Is there no good way to automate these things?

Comment: And apologies in advance if these questions sound stupid to you as you are a super user and metaphorically PhD while I still trying to learn A,B,C. I am learning data analysis for my own use (and to reduce repetitive tasks)

Comment: @GauravArora Automating things is definitely good, but for *two* distinct things it’s almost always more readable to write them out individually rather than using a loop. And you don’t need to use `as.data.frame(data$test)`, the data is *already* a `data.frame` — so you can use it directly as `data$test`, and there’s also no need to assign it to another variable — though of course you *can*, if that makes things clearer.